# Azure - Cannot edit Application Settings. Says they are deleted?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Whenever I create a new App on Azure I cannot edit any of the Application Settings as it says they are deleted? What is going on here?

TIA,
Alex

[image]

Comment: Open a support ticket. This is not a common behavior.

Comment: Any chance that you had created an App Service, deleted it, and then made it again with the same name? I have seen a similar behavior when doing that.

Comment: @JustinPatten Yeah that is exactly what I did

Comment: Try from a different browser or clear your cache. That seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: @JustinPatten That worked , thanks! Put this as an answer so you can get the internet points :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can happen when you have created an App Service, deleted it, and then made it again with the same name.

Try from a different browser or clear your cache.